# child elements go to new line even when they do not exceed parent width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make my 3 cards to be in a same line.
I calculate `width` of every child with their `margin` and the result is exact `width` size of the container element.
So why there are not 3 cards on a line?
Where is the problem and how can I manage to make it work with 3 elements in same line with those exact sizes of container and elements?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1230px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.cards-wrapper {
  background: orange;
}

.cards {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: start;
}

.card {
  height: 225px;
  width: 370px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 29px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon1.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon2.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon3.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon4.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon5.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon6.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/simonika/pen/ZEQBxZj

Comment: Check this out: http://flexbox.buildwithreact.com/

Comment: the total doesn't match: you will have 1290 with box sizing and 1296 without box-sizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1.) Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to everything (using the `*` selector) to include the borders in the widths.

2.)  The side margins left/right are *added*  for adjacent items, so set a 30px `margin-right` only for the last/third item as shown below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1230px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.cards-wrapper {
  background: orange;
}

.cards {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: start;
}

.card {
  height: 225px;
  width: 370px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 29px 30px;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.card:nth-of-type(3n) {
   margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon1.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon2.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon3.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon4.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon5.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon6.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i forgot to add that i have 

    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        list-style: none;
    }

Thanx. It work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Your math is wrong. You need to factor the left/right margin in six times per line which would bring your 30px down to 20px then account for the border which them becomes 19px.

```
1230 - 370(3) = 120 // total remaining space
120 / 6 = 20 // left and right margin size
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1230px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.cards-wrapper {
  background: orange;
}

.cards {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: start;
}

.card {
  height: 225px;
  width: 370px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 29px 19px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon1.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon2.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon3.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon4.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon5.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon6.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that you can omit the border part of the calculation if you set the `box-sizing` to `border-box`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the margin in your class .card, because the margin is added to the space between divs. 
I change the margin to 0, you can use padding to create an space between your border card and your content card.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1230px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.cards-wrapper {
  background: orange;
}

.cards {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: start;
}

.card {
  height: 225px;
  width: 370px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0px 0px; //MARGIN 0
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon1.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon2.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon3.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon4.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon5.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/icon6.png" alt="" class="icon">
      <img src="./img/line-white.png" alt="" class="line">
      <p>bla</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```